# Calling a function from another namespace from a string C#

Tags: c#, string, reflection

I know in C# you can call a function from a string by doing so

```
Type thisType = this.GetType();
MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod(TheCommandString);
theMethod.Invoke(this, userParameters);
```

But I would like something like this

```
CallMethodFromName("Console.WriteLine", "Hello, world!");
```

How do I call a function from another namespace using reflection?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Perhaps you have an XY problem?

Comment: How would the method know which namespace to search for the type that declares the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on "Sticky bit" answer:

```
Type thisType = Type.GetType("System.Console");
MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod("WriteLine");

theMethod.Invoke(null, new object[1] { "Hello" });
```

But you have to be careful about method overloads, because then you can get

```
System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException
```

Also, this aproach isnt the best, and it's a sign of a design problem.
Another thing to take in mind, is using "nameof" operator to tell namespaces names and methods, that's to avoid magic strings.
Applying this on the example i gave:

```
Type thisType = Type.GetType(nameof(System) + "." + nameof(Console));
MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod(nameof(Console.WriteLine));

theMethod.Invoke(null, new object[1] { "Hello" });
```

Then the caller:

```
CallMethodFromName(nameof(Console) + "." + nameof(Console.WriteLine), "Hello, world!");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Type.GetType()` to get a type by namespace and name.

```
...
Type thisType = Type.GetType("System.Console");
MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod("WriteLine");
...
```